# Getting error while linking GDAL on MacOS 11.6

Tags: error, rgdal, macos

```
(base) sushil@MacbookPro ~ % brew link gdal
```

> Linking /usr/local/Cellar/gdal/3.3.2_3... Error: Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/GDAL-3.3.2-py3.9.egg-info

```
(base) sushil@MacbookPro ~ %
```